# Getting Phone number from the user of facebook through javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook

I need to get the email address of the user who login in my webapp through facebook. Everything is fine, but at some people using phone number instead of email address to login to their fb account. I need to get the phone number of the user who using phone number instead of email address. How can I get that please find the code below that I have tried so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
      alert("JSON "+JSON.stringify(response));
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      testAPI();
    } 
  }
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'xxx',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.4' // use version 2.4
  });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me?fields=name,email', function(response) {
        alert("response "+JSON.stringify(response));
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible – the API provides no access to a user’s phone number.

If you don’t get an email, but you need one – then you have to ask the user to input one after FB login. (And if you need it to be verified, via something like a double opt-in – then you have to implement that yourself as well.)